# Python: mplot3d, plot a 3D solid shape that includes dots inside

Tags: python, 3d, matplotlib, plot, shapes

I am trying to plot in python using mplot3d, a solid shape that includes inside, a group of dots that are represented in a 3d space. Perhaps the images will clarify my question.

[image: Dots in spaces] [image]

I was thinking of a sphere but also an irregular solid could work. If it is a sphere, the distance between the two farthest dots of the group would be the diameter of the solid. If there is another python library that you know to accomplish this easier, I would not mind using it.

So, what would be the code to generate this solid shape?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Have a look at `mayavi`, http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/  particularly its `mlab` interface. http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/examples.html  `mplot3d` doesn't actually do "true" 3D plotting, which you'll need for what you're wanting to do.